# is there a way to work with php and mysql just by using notepad++ and mysql server 5.0?

Tags: php, mysql, database, odbc

i had previously installed xammp and phpstorm but they show this error-

```
18:05:38  [mysql]   Problem detected!
18:05:38  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini" MySQL"!
18:05:38  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
18:05:38  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
18:05:38  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
18:05:38  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

i have read every possible solution on stackoverflow, tried every possible solution but the problem still persists. even myphpadmin shows connection error.

i will be making my first php project( with database connectivity), so kindly tell me the connection code as i want to code in notepad++ using just mysql server 5.0

Comment: You must already have a mysql server running. Or another application on port 3306.

Comment: Looks like your are trying to install a new MySQL Server instance in a computer with MySQL already installed, ...in the other hand the question is not being explained in the description of your question.

Comment: yes i had installed mysql server 5.0 previously. so before i installed xampp, i uninstalled mysql server 5.0, but still the problem persists. i also checked in the task manager but port 3306 is not in use by any other program.

Comment: this question should be in https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com , not stackoverflow.com - thus i voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have uninstalled MySql Server 5.0 , uninstall Xampp too. And restart the Computer and again reinstall Xampp. With Xampp you can use PhpMyAdmin. So , I think no need to install MySql Server again. But , If you want you can Install.

If you are doing your First PHP Project , I think it's good to use MVC Structure. You can use MVC to Data Insert , View , Update , Delete and Login. And when you create Login , you should make with Sessions. Otherwise , anyone can access that page without login.

And there is one more thing. There are MySql and MySqli. Both are same. But , latest one is MySqli. So , you should make your Project with MySqli. If you use MySql you can run that Project on the Localhost without any trouble. But , when you Upload your Project to a Server , there are errors like this below picture. But , if you use MySqli you can run Project on Localhost and Server without any trouble.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just like the error says, there's an executable file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\` named `mysqld-nt` already using the ports that your mysql server is configured to use! thus, either reconfigure your mysql server to use different ports, or get rid of `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt` before starting your mysql server. it's been a while since i used xampp, but i *think* the mysql configuration file for xampp is in `C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf` by default. or if you're having problems deleting `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt`, check out LockHunter: https://lockhunter.com/index.htm